# DataTables - um único campo de pesquisa para várias tabelas

Tags: javascript, html

Estou com um problema que é:
tenho uma única tabela que a mesma se repete todos os dias (todas tem as mesmas colunas) o que diferencia é o dia e as informações do dia. Gostaria de um único campo de busca para todas as tabelas.

antes eu usava o DataTables e funcionava perfeitamente mais hoje uso abas (Collapse Bootstrap) e depois disso DataTables parou de funcionar.

Alguém, conhece alguma maneira de usar um único campo de pesquisa para todas as tabelas independe do dia?

ex: se eu quiser pesquisar o cliente joão seja os pedidos de hoje, ontem e qualquer outro dia iria mostrar-lo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: você pode usar um campo único apenas se tiver um campo único na sua tabela no banco de dados. porque não usar o ID do registo?

Comment: Olá Luís, não entendi muito bem poderia me explicar melhor? desde já agradeço.